# return the rest of a list in Haskell recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

Hey guys so I'm trying to create a simple program to delete the first occurence of a element then return the rest of the list.
It's been a while and I'm wondering why I'm getting this parse error on line 8

```
module deleteFirst where
deleteFirst :: (Eq a) => a ->[a] -> [a]

deleteFirst toDelete [] = []
deleteFirst toDelete (a:as) =
    if(toDelete == a) then as
    else a:(deleteFirst toDelete as)
```

Any input? Thanks guy

Comment: next time please copy and paste the error message as is in its entirety. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parse error is on column 8, not line 8, and it is because module names must start with an upper case letter.

Comment: Such a simple solution i knew it. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You got the answer, but I'd like to point out another solution:

```
deleteFirst x xs = u ++ (drop 1 v) where (u,v) = break (==x) xs
```